# In Excel VBA, how can I test if the active cell is in a certain row or column?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I need to prevent a macro from running if the user hasn't selected a cell in a certain column or row. How can I detect which row/column the selected cell is in to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your worksheet is activated, then you can use `Selection.Row` and `Selection.Column`. In the case you have multiple cells selected - you will get the row and column numbers for the top left cell of your selection.